# Adding Value Fields in a different data set in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2005, reportingservices-2005, bids

In this question it answered how to add two different datasets, 
[SSRS - Expression using different dataset fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9676149/ssrs-expression-using-different-dataset-fields)

I tried that kind of approach and here is my expression

```
=First(Fields!count.Value, "remclass1")+First(Fields!count.Value, "db_IACS")
```

the problem is that only the first value is being Calculated like this 
[image: aa]

I added the Pulled out **COUNT** to the Expired **Count**, i want it to be added per Row
only the first part

**For instance:**

```
Column 7 (Count) = Column1(Count) + Column 4 (count) //**per Row**
The value of row 1 column 7 would be column 1 + column 4 row 1
the value of row 2 column 7 would be column 1 + column 4 row 2
```

The Pulled out table 
(Consists of Count, Grams, Principal) are on the data set **db_IACS**
and the Expired table(Consists of Count,Grams,Prinicipal) are in the dataset **remclass1**

So any help how to do it? how to add the two columns (in a different dataset)

Thanks :)

Comment: Do they need to be two different datasets? Could you do this by joining the tables in SQL?

Comment: @ChrisLätta that's what i think, ill try to join them in one single query.

Comment: @User6675636b20796f7521: Please do not go back through your posts and edit contextual information out of them, such that they invalidate existing answers. Simply don't post that information in the first place, if you classify it as confidential.

Comment: @Matt hello kind sir. I know i have showed some informations that i shouldnt have, thats why im fixing it, can you help me update some of my questions and the answers provided to them so that the answer wont be invlidated? I really need you help please.

Comment: @User6675636b20796f7521: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85329/matt-and-user-6675636b20796f7521

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this in SQL, as follows:

```
SELECT db_IACS.count as PulledOut_Count, db_IACS.Grams AS PulledOut_Grams, db_IACS.Principle AS PulledOut_Principle,
    remclass1.count as remclass1_Count, remclass1.Grams AS remclass1_Grams, remclass1.Principle AS remclass1_Principle
FROM db_AICS
LEFT OUTER JOIN remclass1 ON db_IACS.Id = remclass1.Id
```

Then just deal with everything in the one dataset.