# SSRS datasets Scope with IIF

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, reporting-services

I have an issue with SSRS. In a filed called "InformacionDirecta" from the dataset "Solicitud" I have the following expression:

```
=iif(Fields!ModifInfoDirecta.Value,chr(254), chr(168))
```

It works well and shows me the type of checkbox I want according the value returned by the field (true or false) but, when I add another dataset ("Dataset2") the report shows me an error that says:

> "the value expression for the textbox refers directly to the field without specifying a dataset aggregate".

How could I solve that?

Comment: It's tough to be sure without seeing your report, but you probably have a table without a Dataset defined. All tables need a Dataset; but if you haven't specified a Dataset for a table but only have one Dataset in the report it will just use that and work fine. But as soon as you add another Dataset you will have to explicitly define the Dataset for all tables in the report.

Comment: ^ What he said.  Read about "Data regions"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9676149/ssrs-expression-using-different-dataset-fields