# Adding from two different reportitems

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to add from two separate text boxes from different datasets I had to create a code to summarize (codes below) giving a total.   What I am trying to do is get  `GapTotal + GapTotal2` together into a separate dataset. Unfortunately I get a blank.   Can anyone help?  Thank you in advance

```
Public GapTotal AS Integer = 0
Public Function Sum(ByVal Value As Integer) As Integer
GapTotal = GapTotal + Value
Return Value
End Function


Public GapTotal2 AS Integer = 0
Public Function SumIt(ByVal Value As Integer) As Integer
GapTotal2 = GapTotal2 + Value
Return Value

End Function
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please can you improve the formatting of your question?

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible approaches l can think of here.

First reference the values in each dataset and add the values see this posting -  [Stack Overflow posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9676149/ssrs-expression-using-different-dataset-fields)

Second place the values from each data into a control eg a text box, then add the values in each text box see - [SQL Server Central posting](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1607152-150-1.aspx)

Comment: Thank you!  I appreciate your response.